# Why are WebSockets slower than AJAX $.post()?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, websocket

I have been locally testing the difference between `WebSockets` and `$.post()` and have found $.post() to be consistantly **76% faster** than WebSockets in the following scenario:

**The scenario**

1. Client posts a command ("start") to server.
2. Server responds with command ("ready").
3. Client posts a command ("file") to server.
4. Server responds with the contents of a 1.4MB (approx.) text file containing the word "Lorem".
5. Client receives this file and repeats the cycle 10 times.

Client `AJAX` $.post():

```
httpPost('start', 0);
function httpPost(cmd, iteration) {
    $.post('http://path/to/server', {cmd:cmd}, function(data){
        switch(data) {
        case "ready":
            // request file
            httpPost('file', iteration);
            break;
        case "received":
            if(iteration == 9) {
                // total time taken is recorded here (omitted)
            }else{      
                httpPost('start', ++iteration);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(data.indexOf('Lorem') > -1) {
            // acknowledge receipt of file
            httpPost('Lorem', iteration);
        }

    });
}
```

Server PostController:

```
@WebServlet("/post")
public class PostController extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String cmd = req.getParameter("cmd");

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        if(cmd != null) {
            switch(cmd) {
            case "start":
                out.append("ready");
                break;
            case "file":
                String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/file.txt");
                String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(absoluteDiskPath));
                out.append(contents);
                break;
            case "concurrency":
                out.append("concurrency");
                break;
            case "Lorem":
                out.append("received");
                break;
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Client `WebSockets API`:

```
startWebSocket(); // open a single websocket connection and request a file 10 times
function startWebSocket() {
    var url = "ws://path/to/server";
    var socket = new WebSocket(url);
    var iteration = 0;

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
         if (event.data.indexOf('ready') > -1) {
             // request file
             socket.send('file');
         }

         if(event.data.indexOf('Lorem') > -1) {
            // acknowledge receipt of file
            socket.send('Lorem');
         }

         if(event.data.indexOf('received') > -1) {
            if(iteration == 9) {
              // total time taken is recorded here (omitted)
            }else{          
                socket.send('start');
                iteration++;
            }
         }
     }

     socket.onopen = function (event) {
     };

     socket.onclose = function (event) {
     };

     socket.onerror = function (event) {
     };
}
```

Server `ServerEndPoint`:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/server")
public class Server{

    private static ArrayList<Session> sessionList = new ArrayList<Session>();

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable t) {
        sessionList.remove(session);
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        try {
            sessionList.add(session);
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("ready");

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sessionList.remove(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String msg) throws JSONException {

        String output = "";
        if(msg.equals("file")) {

            try {
                URL resource = getClass().getResource("/");
                String path = resource.getPath();
                String absoluteDiskPath = path + "../../resources/file.txt";
                output = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(absoluteDiskPath));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(msg.equals("Lorem")) {
            output = "received";
        }

        if(msg.equals("start")) {
            output = "ready";
        }

        for (int i = 0, size = sessionList.size(); i < size; i++) {
            try {
                sessionList.get(i).getBasicRemote().sendText(output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This test was completed locally using JQuery's $.post() and JavaScripts Websocket API. The servers were written in Java.

On the last test the AJAX $.post() method completed 10 calls in **0.450** seconds, whereas the 10 Websocket API calls completed in **1.877** seconds.

I would have expected the 10 websocket calls to complete the fastest, because of the lower number of headers being sent with each message.

So, why is JQuery's $.post() faster than WebSockets?

[image]

Comment: my initial hunch was that the posts (which are async by default) were all happening in parallel and the calls for the websocket call was happening synchronously. have you checked with Fiddler/Firebug etc to see if you have 9 websockets opening? the trade off is that if you have one websocket open and treat it like a pipe that should be faster but if you have multiple open that's less efficient

Comment: Does the performance difference decrease as you perform more calls and requests? If I understand correctly, the WebSocket handshake *can* add initial latency, but once communication is established, data transfer is faster than with Ajax because WebSockets does not share Ajax's HTTP header overhead.

Comment: @GordonMacDonald Yes I'm just using one single WebSocket connection. Although the AJAX posts are async by default, they are being called in a sequential manner - the `httpPost()` method calls itself recursively depending on the data it receives from the server.

Comment: You're creating a new connection each time. HTTP won't do that (not with Keep-Alive at least). A better comparison would be to create one socket and send 9 messages using it.

Comment: @Paulpro After the httpPost() has finished calling itself 9 times(10 calls in total). A single websocket connection is then opened afterwards and 10 requests for the file are made on the single websocket connection.

Comment: @twernt Yes that's what I expected to find. But in the above scenario a file exchange consisting of 3 HTTP posts is faster than a single websocket connection consisting of 2 messages per file transfer (plus a 3rd to reset the message sequence on the next iteration).

Comment: Oh I see that now. Is the HTTP server serving it gzipped and/or is it being cached client-side?

Comment: Try it with 9 different incompressible (random bytes) files.

Comment: @Paulpro I tried it with 10 different files of which the contents must be retrieved. Still the same results. $.post() is approximately 75% faster in this scenario. (post, wait for contents of file, post again, wait for response)..

Comment: Were the files randomly generated binary? Anything else will compress.

Comment: How can I test that?

Comment: Hey, I didn't get notified about your reply, because you forgot to add @paulpro. If you're using some sort of unix based OS you can use the `dd` command to read from /dev/random and put the output in a file to use for your tests.